# libstdc++ Error: `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, c++, cross-compilation

I was trying to cross-compile dlib for Raspberry Pi, using the arm-linux-gnueabihf compiler.

After successful runs of `cmake` and `make -j4`, I ran `python setup.py bdist_wheel --repackage`, which created the nencessary .so files which I later copied to my Pi's `/usr/lib` using `scp`.

Now when I run `import dlib` in IDLE, I get the following error:

`` ImportError: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by dlib/dlib.so) ``

Here's the ouput of `strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX`:

`GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20`

This means that the error is legitimate, but my libstdc++ is already at its newest version on the Pi. What can I do to get that 3.4.22 version installed on the Pi? Or maybe, if it's possible, to compile it again against 3.4.20? How can I set a compiler flag for that?

Comment: You should recompile.  As to how to set the cross compiler to do so, you are better off asking on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).  I'd like to believe you don't need another toolchain...

Comment: @goldilocks I have recompiled but I get the error. I believe I might need to downgrade my own system's `libstdc++` but I am not sure.

Comment: Any chance this question can be migrated to SO?

Comment: You would be better off copy pasting it to there since migrated questions retain their timestamp (i.e., 3 hours ago, which is a long time on S.O.).

Answer (score 4):

It appears you used a g++ 6 cross-compiler (default install on Debian 9?) then attempted to run the resulting binary on Raspbian 8 Jessie. You can see gcc's symbol versioning guide [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) where g++ 4.9 ties to GLIBCXX_3.4.20 and g++ 6 to GLIBCXX_3.4.22.

> What can I do to get that 3.4.22 version installed on the Pi?

Perhaps the most straightforward approach is to update to Raspbian 9 Stretch. It's based on gcc/g++ 6.3.

> Or maybe, if it's possible, to compile it again against 3.4.20? How can I set a compiler flag for that?

If it's not convenient to upgrade your Pi, you can instead use a different cross-compiler. You cannot merely use a flag because g++ is quite intertwined with libstdc++'s version.

```
git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools
```

At the time of writing that toolchain is geared for gcc 4.9 / Raspbian 8 Jessie. Or if you prefer to continue using system packages installed via `apt`, try this:

```
sudo apt remove g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf
sudo apt install g++-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.9 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.9 10
sudo update-alternatives --config arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
sudo update-alternatives --config arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
```

Caveat: that last approach may result in a toolchain that defaults to ARMv7 code, which works for the Pi 2 and 3, but not Pi classic/B+/Zero.